# psr 4 - zf2 load custom class

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

I have ZF2 application where at root level i've my vendor folder. (classic skeleton application)
In vendor there are contained all the libraries that I update and install with composer.

Under vendors have the need to add the custom classes and autoload it.

Use composer and write a autolader like this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
    "ciromar\\": "/vendor/ciromar/src" 
}
```

now the folder structure is as follows:

```
vendor 
--ciromar 
---- src 
------ Log 
-------- Writer 
---------- FileRotator.php (class)
```

the namespace of the class is FileRotator.php

```
namespace ciromar\Log\Writer;
```

the controller of my applications

```
use ciromar\Log\Writer\FileRotator; 

IndexController class extends AbstractActionController 
{
    public function indexAction () 
    {

        $fr = new FileRotator(""); 
    } 
}
```

the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ciromar\Log\Writer\FileRotator' not found in /var/www/html/myapp/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 21
```

Comment: ok i solved. i need to set path in this way `./vendor/ciromar/src`

Answer (score 0):

You should set path in this way

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
   "ciromar\\": "./vendor/ciromar/src" 
}
```

But I think you should not put your custom module to vendor by hands. 
You should develop it like module, next add own module composer.json, next add module to packagist and than require your module in your project composer.json and composer download it to vendor/ automatically.

If you want implement PSR-4 loading for just app module, than place it in app modules directory and add autoloading rule to composer.json

For example
https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/zend-framework-2-using-psr-4-autoloader-in-module/